# Graphql query is firing every time the page is loading. How to save in cache?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo, hasura

I'm having a website where I show different kinds of projects to the user. I'm using `Hasura`, `NextJS` and `Apollo` to make this happen. The problem I have now is that every time I come back to the home page (where I show my projects) the query is getting fired again and has to load all over again. I want to save the data in my cache, but I'm not sure how to do that.

This is how I do it now:

I'm calling the query, when its done loading, I return my Home component with the data.

```
const ProjectList = () => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_PROJECTS);

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return <div>Error!</div>;
  }
  return <Home projects={data.projects} />;
};

export default withApollo({ ssr: true })(ProjectList);
```

In the home component I know can use the data:

```
const Home = ({ projects }) => {
  // rest code...
}
```

I create my apolloClient as the following:

```
export default function createApolloClient(initialState, headers) {
  const ssrMode = typeof window === 'undefined';
  let link;
  if (ssrMode) {
    link = createHttpLink(headers); // executed on server
  } else {
    link = createWSLink(); // executed on client
  }
  return new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode,
    link,
    cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState),
  });
}
```

Is there a way I can save the data in the cache, so I don't have to wait for the loading state every time I come back to the home page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the prebuild feature of nextjs. For this you need to call [getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation) in your **ProjectList.jsx** file. There you have to import your *apollo client* as well as your query, then initialize the client and do the query:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const apollo = require("../../../apollo/apolloClient"); // import client
  const GET_PROJECTS = require("../../../apollo/graphql").GET_PROJECTS; // import query
  const client = apollo.initializeApollo(); //initialize client

  const { data, error } = await client.query({
    query: GET_PROJECTS
  });

  if (!data || error) {
    return {
      notFound: true
    };
  }

  return {
    props: { projects: data.projects } // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
}
```

Comment: @Gho5d When I try this I get the following error: `ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined`

Comment: How does your apolloClient look like? Does it have an initializeApollo function?

Comment: I found the issue. I load images from Firebase Storage and that gives the error. I removed them and now it works fine! I'm gonna have a look into making a S3 bucket to handle the images.

Comment: In that case you only have to put the files into the bucket and make sure that everybody has the rights to access them. If my answer helped, then I'd be happy if you'd accept it ;-)